# What kind of problems cannot be solved using machine learning techniques?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, training

For the problems that can be solved algorithmically.

We have very good formal literature for which problems can be solved in polynomial, exponential time and which cannot. **P/NP/NP-hard**

But do we know some problems in machine learning paradigm for which no model can be trained? (With/without infinite computation capacity)

Answer (score 2):

At least you should be aware of two points:

- P/NP/NP-hard (and all other class of complexities) are thoroughly valid for the machine learning area as well. Because these concepts are related to the fundamental of computations ([theory of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_computation)), and machine learning is not an exception here.
- One of the useful concepts in the complexity of the learning problem is the [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension), [PAC learnability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning), and their related concepts (such as [sample complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_complexity)). Although these concepts can't be enough to measure the time complexity, they are useful for finding the learner model's capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupervised disentanglement learning with arbitrary generative models is impossible without inductive biases [1].

In fact, in general, any kind of learning is impossible without inductive biases.

[1]: [Challenging Common Assumptions in the Unsupervised Learning of Disentangled Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.12359)

Comment: Maybe you could explain what UDL is and why UDL with arbitrary generative models is _impossible_ without inductive bias.